# Cassandra Saving data from file in Java

Tags: java, oop, cassandra, aop

I am using java store data to Cassandra through materiliazed view but I got an issue. The issue is that its not going save data to Cassandra database. I got this error.

```
No columns are defined for Materialized View other than primary key
```

> REATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS sensorkeyspace.maxtable AS select sensor_id,humidity from sensorkeyspace.sensortable where (humidity is not null) PRIMARY KEY (sensor_id)
>   Exception in thread "main" com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: No columns are defined for Materialized View other than primary key
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:50)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DriverThrowables.propagateCause(DriverThrowables.java:37)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:245)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:64)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractSession.execute(AbstractSession.java:39)
>       at sparkproject.SparkApp.main(SparkApp.java:41)
>   Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: No columns are defined for Materialized View other than primary key
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Responses$Error.asException(Responses.java:136)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture.onSet(DefaultResultSetFuture.java:179)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:174)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler.access$2600(RequestHandler.java:43)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.setFinalResult(RequestHandler.java:793)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.RequestHandler$SpeculativeExecution.onSet(RequestHandler.java:627)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:1012)
>       at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Dispatcher.channelRead0(Connection.java:935)
>       at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:342)
>       at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:328)

Comment: could you please provide your source table? If your source table primary key is same as MV then it will throw this exception.

Comment: But I want to send that primary key to other table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that you're creating the materialized view with the same primary key as a main table.  Please check the MV definition

Comment: This still give me this error. "No Columns are define for materiliazed view other than primary key"

Comment: Please share the definitions of your main table and materialized view

Comment: in my main table I have sens_id, humid,temp and I want to store this in other table I use this query

Comment: Please update your post with CQL statements that create a table, and materialized view...

Comment: I have a database where my keyspace is abc and table is dhf. i already have data in this table where my primary key in this tabe is k_id i want to retrieve
 data through this query

     select * from abc.dhf where  PRIMARY KEY (k_d) IS NOT NULL ;
But when ever i execute this query it give me error in cql the error is 

> SyntaxException: line 1:48 no viable alternative at input 'PRIMARY' (...* from abc.dhl where  [PRIMARY]...)

Comment: This is wrong syntax for CQL query, and such queries won't work. Please refer documentation for CQL on syntax of SELECT query. And Cassandra isn't designed for bulk fetch of data as you want